# using XnView for screen shot/capture on a multi monitor setup

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, screenshot, xnview

Is there a way to capture a specific monitor (or all monitors) with XnView? Currently it only captures my "middle" monitor (I have a three monitor setup with Windows 10 and XnView 2.49.3)?

I'm not focused on XnView any other solution will do as well. I'm using XnView to capture multiple screenshot (e.g. to create a installation tutorial). It captures each screenshot in a tab. Afterwards I can sort, edit and save the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Far from optimal: as a workaround I use the "screenshot with autosave" function from Windows 10 (Win+Prt). Then I use XnView to view the folder where the screenshots have been saved.